# Salesforce files unable to access document with partner user

Tags: apex, sharing, campaign, files

We have the following scenario:
- Partner user as access to Campaign record
- An internal user add a File related to this Campaign Record

Partner user is not able to access the content document, and file is not visible when accessing the campaign record within Community.

Instead, on the other way around, when partner user adds a file, internal users can access it through the campaign record.

We have tried by adding a new `ContentDocumentLink with LinkedEntityId = "User or Group Id"`, but we get below error:

> INVALID ACCESS ON CROSS REFERENCE ENTITY

Someone has got more info about "how to share files related to a sObject"?

---

With a Partner User Profile the visibility is set "All Users" and ShareType= "V", but if shared file with a not Partner User profile, the visibility is set "Internal Users" and ShareType= "V" Or "I"

Comment: What is the Visibility and ShareType on the ContentDocumentLink?